# Re-asking questions from other sites

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across this question, which is attributed to an almost identical question on a different site. The other site has a perfectly good answer to the question.
Should this sort of thing be discouraged, or is it considered okay during the beta stage?

[How do I know if my plants are already fully grown in Plants vs Zombies?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294/how-do-i-know-if-my-plants-are-already-fully-grown-in-plants-vs-zombies)

Regardless, kudos to the asker for the attribution and not trying to claim it as their own.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in the comments, I'd be more inclined to wait for them to be asked organically (when one needs to).

We don't need **all the questions** about gaming to be asked on the very first day.

Answer (score 3):

The goal of the StackExchange Q&A sites is to become a complete resource for all information on any given subject, and that a Google search will lead to said site, which has an in-depth, carefully edited, correct and up-to-date answer.

The problem with blogs, forums and FAQ-type sites is that they tend to become outdated very quickly. They're also very biased, as they're written once by one person, and there is very rarely discussion and editing.

So maybe somebody goes around asking the same question to several sites, but hopefully the question and answer on StackExchange is the one that is kept alive and up to date, because other posts on other sites tend to die off.

I don't agree with excessive content seeding, but I think this form of question duplication is perfectly fine to achieve the goal of becoming a central repository.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with Juan, I myself am [actually guilty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380/at-what-points-in-forza-3-do-you-start-races-in-higher-positions) of doing this as well. However, in my case, the other site doesn't actually have a good answer -- it has what little I'd been able to deduce through playing the game, and the answer's frankly not very helpful.

So in general, I agree that we should ask questions when answers are needed/desired, not just pick out all the others from other sites and seed away like mad.

(And thus, the three questions I asked today are in fact three I want answers to. :)

Answer (score 1):

It brings up a good question though, and I actually need an answer somewhat. We have been running EpicAdvice.com for 7 months now with a decent community running and quite a few questions. Do we re-ask questions from Gaming.SE, does Gaming.SE re-ask questions from EpicAdvice, or do we direct people at one another (not that we really get many non-wow related questions).

It's an interesting situation.

Comment: An example of one way to handle it: http://epicadvice.com/questions/5948/what-is-the-easiest-class-to-level  --  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/180/easiest-world-of-warcraft-class-to-level

Comment: I don't know if this is a ggod solution but as all epic advice questions should be gaming related and as epicadvice is somehow base on SO maybe it'll be possible to import the questions here ?

Or put all wow related question on the more specialized epicadvice.

Comment: @jesta - what is the plan for epicadvice? I'm a member there too and like it, but I wonder if that site (and it's content) ought to be merged into this one??

Comment: It's staying it's own entity for now, we haven't discussed anything yet with Robert and the SE crew. However, with the Cataclysm NDA lifted, we are going to start pushing hard this friday for Cataclysm content via a contest. No plans on merging into anything or converting to anything yet, we are still exploring everything as well as its viability.

Comment: I rather have a seperate EpicAdvice, as it is big enough to stay on it's own.

Comment: @MarmouCorp having a separate (SE) site for the top games is an interesting concept