# Is it acceptable to re-ask an unanswered question I posted on another site?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Around a month ago I posted a question on a different site (GameFaqs). Since then the question has gone unanswered. Would it be acceptable for me to re-ask the question on Arqade?

Comment: See https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/re-asking-questions-from-other-sites

Comment: Seems the general consensus is its fine so long as you aren't bombing sites within a rapid time frame. Seeing that it's been a month, it should be fine.

Answer (score 8):

Seems fine to me.

You probably shouldn't crosspost your question everywhere at once, but if you're still looking for an answer, there's really nothing wrong with reposting something here.

Answer (score 5):

**I actually don't see any reason at all why it wouldn't be acceptable.**

This entire platform tries to offer its information in a self-contained way.
More often than not, information provided here can be found elsewhere online (but here it is more likely to be parsed, corroborated, and, eventually, of an altogether higher quality).

**Whether or not *you* post the same question on multiple websites, or your question just happens to exist elsewhere, doesn't matter at all.**

With the exception of questions asking after information that can very easily and quickly be attained using a search engine, I feel that what (information-wise) happens elsewhere on the Innernette doesn't have consequences for the information here.

Answer (score 3):

I would go in the same way, I don't mind seeing questions that are asked somewhere else be asked here too. Hell, I did it a couple of times, asking a question here and also asking it on the game's subreddit at the same time, to hit a bigger pool of answer-givers

**BUT** where I would bring my mod hammer down is if we see a question/answer from another site be literally copy/pasted here. Because I would assume you are just throwing questions here to try and boost your score.

Comment: Good point! Always good to just don't be lazy about any contributions.